Find intersection point between line and ellipse in Python
I am trying to find the point which intersects with the line and the ellipse. I can find the point manually as seen in the code but how can I find it automatically. Also when the red point is inside the ellipse the green point should also be projected on to the ellipse when extending the line. How can I solve this? Code examples are appreciated! Thanks!

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Parameters
ellipse_center = np.array([238, 239])
ellipse_axes = np.array([150, 100])  # Semi-major and semi-minor axes
ellipse_angle = np.radians(70)  # Angle of rotation (in radians)

line_point1 = ellipse_center  # Point on the line
line_point2 = np.array([341, 125])  # Another point on the line (moving point)

# Initialize OpenCV window
window_name = "Projecting Point on Rotated Ellipse"
cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
canvas = np.zeros((400, 400, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    
while True:
    # Clear canvas
    canvas.fill(0)

    # Draw the rotated ellipse
    cv2.ellipse(canvas, tuple(ellipse_center), tuple(ellipse_axes), np.degrees(ellipse_angle), 0, 360, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # Draw the moving point
    cv2.circle(canvas, (int(line_point2[0]), int(line_point2[1])), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # Draw the center point of the ellipse
    cv2.circle(canvas, tuple(ellipse_center), 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)

    # Draw the line between moving point and the center of the ellipse
    cv2.line(canvas, (int(line_point2[0]), int(line_point2[1])), tuple(ellipse_center), (0, 0, 255), 1)

    intersection_points = (310, 159) # <- How to find this?
    cv2.circle(canvas, intersection_points, 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)

    # Show canvas
    cv2.imshow(window_name, canvas)

    # Exit if 'q' is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Close OpenCV window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

When using the ellipse equation and the line equation I get this:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# Parameters
ellipse_center = np.array([238, 239])
ellipse_axes = np.array([150, 100])  # Semi-major and semi-minor axes
ellipse_angle = np.radians(70)  # Angle of rotation (in radians)

line_point1 = ellipse_center  # Point on the line
line_point2 = np.array([341, 125])  # Another point on the line (moving point)

# Ellipse equation: (x - h)^2 / a^2 + (y - k)^2 / b^2 = 1, where (h, k) is the center of the ellipse
def ellipse_eq(params):
    x, y = params
    h, k = ellipse_center
    a, b = ellipse_axes
    return ((x - h) ** 2 / a ** 2) + ((y - k) ** 2 / b ** 2) - 1

# Line equation: y = mx + c
def line_eq(x):
    m = (line_point2[1] - line_point1[1]) / (line_point2[0] - line_point1[0])
    c = line_point1[1] - m * line_point1[0]
    return m * x + c

# Intersection of the ellipse and the line
def intersection_point():
    x_intercept = fsolve(lambda x: ellipse_eq([x, line_eq(x)]), line_point2[0])
    y_intercept = line_eq(x_intercept)
    return x_intercept[0], y_intercept[0]

# Initialize OpenCV window
window_name = "Projecting Point on Rotated Ellipse"
cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
canvas = np.zeros((400, 400, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

while True:
    # Clear canvas
    canvas.fill(0)

    # Draw the rotated ellipse
    cv2.ellipse(canvas, tuple(ellipse_center), tuple(ellipse_axes), np.degrees(ellipse_angle), 0, 360, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # Draw the moving point
    cv2.circle(canvas, (int(line_point2[0]), int(line_point2[1])), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # Draw the center point of the ellipse
    cv2.circle(canvas, tuple(ellipse_center), 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)

    # Draw the line between moving point and the center of the ellipse
    cv2.line(canvas, (int(line_point2[0]), int(line_point2[1])), tuple(ellipse_center), (0, 0, 255), 1)

    # Find and draw the intersection point
    intersection_points = intersection_point()
    cv2.circle(canvas, (int(intersection_points[0]), int(intersection_points[1])), 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)

    # Show canvas
    cv2.imshow(window_name, canvas)

    # Exit if 'q' is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Close OpenCV window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Which does not solve my problem. What am I doing wrong here?
EDIT:
Using MBo's approach with the code:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Parameters
ellipse_center = np.array([238, 239])
ellipse_axes = np.array([150, 100])  # Semi-major and semi-minor axes
ellipse_angle = np.radians(70)  # Angle of rotation (in radians)

line_point1 = ellipse_center  # Point on the line (ellipse center)
line_point2 = np.array([341, 125])  # Another point on the line (moving point)

# Initialize OpenCV window
window_name = "Projecting Point on Rotated Ellipse"
cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
canvas = np.zeros((400, 400, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

while True:
    # Clear canvas
    canvas.fill(0)

    # Draw the rotated ellipse
    cv2.ellipse(canvas, tuple(ellipse_center), tuple(ellipse_axes), np.degrees(ellipse_angle), 0, 360, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # Draw the moving point
    cv2.circle(canvas, (int(line_point2[0]), int(line_point2[1])), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # Draw the center point of the ellipse
    cv2.circle(canvas, tuple(ellipse_center), 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)

    # Draw the line between moving point and the center of the ellipse
    cv2.line(canvas, (int(line_point2[0]), int(line_point2[1])), tuple(ellipse_center), (0, 0, 255), 1)

    # Calculate the intersection point
    t = np.arctan2(line_point2[1] - ellipse_center[1], line_point2[0] - ellipse_center[0]) - np.arctan2(np.sin(ellipse_angle) * ellipse_axes[0], np.cos(ellipse_angle) * ellipse_axes[1])
    x_intersection = ellipse_center[0] + ellipse_axes[0] * np.cos(t) * np.cos(ellipse_angle) - ellipse_axes[1] * np.sin(t) * np.sin(ellipse_angle)
    y_intersection = ellipse_center[1] + ellipse_axes[0] * np.cos(t) * np.sin(ellipse_angle) + ellipse_axes[1] * np.sin(t) * np.cos(ellipse_angle)
    intersection_point = (int(x_intersection), int(y_intersection))

    # Draw the intersection point
    cv2.circle(canvas, intersection_point, 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)

    # Show canvas
    cv2.imshow(window_name, canvas)

    # Exit if 'q' is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Close OpenCV window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Gets me:


this is a math/geometry problem, not a problem of programming.

OK, I think I now understand what you are asking. My answer is edited.

First rotate the line back by ellipse_angle so that it corresponds to the unrotated ellipse.
Substitute (for y) the equation of the line (y=mx+c) into the equation of the ellipse (x-h)2/a2+(y-k)2/b2=1. This will give a quadratic in x which can be solved by the usual quadratic-equation formula.
The quadratic is Ax2+Bx+C=0, where, on rearrangement,
A=a2m2+b2
B=2a2m(c-k)-2b2h
C=b2h2+a2(c-k)2-a2b2
Solve for x and get y from the equation of the line. Be careful to get the correct quadratic root.
Then rotate the intersection point back again by ellipse_angle.
As with any quadratic equation you can run into occasions with a single root (line just touches the ellipse) and no roots (line misses the ellipse).
Code below - I have indicated the modified section of your code.
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Parameters
ellipse_center = np.array([238, 239])
ellipse_axes = np.array([150, 100])  # Semi-major and semi-minor axes
ellipse_angle = np.radians(70)  # Angle of rotation (in radians)

line_point1 = ellipse_center  # Point on the line (ellipse center)
line_point2 = np.array([341, 125])  # Another point on the line (moving point)

# Initialize OpenCV window
window_name = "Projecting Point on Rotated Ellipse"
cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
canvas = np.zeros((400, 400, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

while True:
    # Clear canvas
    canvas.fill(0)

    # Draw the rotated ellipse
    cv2.ellipse(canvas, tuple(ellipse_center), tuple(ellipse_axes), np.degrees(ellipse_angle), 0, 360, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # Draw the moving point
    cv2.circle(canvas, (int(line_point2[0]), int(line_point2[1])), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # Draw the center point of the ellipse
    cv2.circle(canvas, tuple(ellipse_center), 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)

    # Draw the line between moving point and the center of the ellipse
    cv2.line(canvas, (int(line_point2[0]), int(line_point2[1])), tuple(ellipse_center), (0, 0, 255), 1)


    ############## MODIFIED SECTION ############
    # Rotate the line back to an unrotated ellipse
    theta = np.arctan2( line_point2[1] - line_point1[1], line_point2[0] - line_point1[0] ) - ellipse_angle
    m = np.tan( theta )
    c = line_point1[1] - m * line_point1[0]
    a, b, h, k = ellipse_axes[0], ellipse_axes[1], ellipse_center[0], ellipse_center[1]
    A = ( a * m ) ** 2 + b ** 2
    B = 2 * ( a ** 2 * m * ( c - k ) - b ** 2 * h )
    C = ( b * h ) ** 2 + ( a * ( c - k ) ) ** 2 - ( a * b ) ** 2
    discriminant = B ** 2 - 4 * A * C
    # Intersection of back-rotated line with back-rotated ellipse (need correct root)
    theta = np.mod( theta, 2 * np.pi )
    x1 = ( -B + np.sqrt( discriminant ) ) / ( 2 * A )                 # quadratic solution (larger root)
    if theta > 0.5 * np.pi and theta < 1.5 * np.pi: x1 = -B/A - x1    # need other root
    y1 = m * x1 + c
    # Rotate the line forward again
    x1, y1 = h + ( x1 - h ) * np.cos( ellipse_angle ) - ( y1 - k ) * np.sin( ellipse_angle ),  k + ( x1 - h ) * np.sin( ellipse_angle ) + ( y1 - k ) * np.cos( ellipse_angle )
    intersection_point = (int(x1), int(y1))
    ############## END OF MODIFIED SECTION ############

    # Draw the intersection point
    cv2.circle(canvas, intersection_point, 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)

    # Show canvas
    cv2.imshow(window_name, canvas)

    # Exit if 'q' is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Close OpenCV window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Output:


Thanks could you provide a code example I can test with?

OK, I've managed to sort out the code.

OK, I found my old answer for similar question, and approach is rather simple
Solve simpler problem for axis-aligned ellipse:
Rotate line end point coordinates by -theta
Extend (or shrink) ellipse along OY axis by a/b times, making circle
Find intersection point
Make backward shrinking
Make backward rotation
Checked it now, Delphi code does work
(ellipse center cx, cy, and line end poiont px, py, rotation angle fi)
px1 := (px-cx) * Cos(fi) + (py-cy) * Sin(fi);
py1 := -(px-cx) * Sin(fi) + (py-cy) * Cos(fi); 
py1 := py1 * a / b;
plen := hypot(px1, py1);
ix := a * px1 / plen;
iy := a * py1 / plen;
iy := iy * b / a;

//finally intersection point:
fx := cx + Round(ix * Cos(fi) - iy * Sin(fi));
fy := cy + Round(ix * Sin(fi) + iy * Cos(fi));


